# On click of a checkbox of matching GUID from table row, How to highlight exact GUID Modal member

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Problem Statement :

We have a table of rows with unique GUID's and also Revit 3D Modal members associated with GUID's.

I am trying to highlight exact GUID Modal member On click of a checkbox of matching GUID from table row.

Please suggest on triggering point to highlight modal member dynamically.

Please find the attached screenshot for the reference.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJC3F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of finding the object with your GUID. I would recommend using the [Model.getExternalIdMapping](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getexternalidmapping-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method. It will generate a dictionary mapping *internal* IDs ("dbIDs") to *external* IDs (in this case, Revit GUIDs). You can then use this map in an "inverted" way, finding a dbID for a specific GUID.

Once you know the dbID of your object inside the viewer, you can use [viewer.select](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#select-dbids-model-selectiontype), [viewer.isolate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#isolate-node-model), or similar methods to provide visual indication.